# how to run python script to display webpage for auto login on one click

Tags: python, browser, authentication

I have my python script which I guess is fine. I want to keep the script on the desktop and upon one click I want the script to run and open a browser(IE or firefox or chrome) and perform the script i.e. to log-in to a website.

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib 

username = 'xyzusername' 
password = 'xyzpassword' 

cj = cookielib.CookieJar() 

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj)) 

login_data = urllib.urlencode({'userid' : username, 'pass' : password}) 

resp = opener.open('http://www.gmail.com') 

resp.read()

print resp
```

How do I run the script? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm, your script is logging into a web site, but it's not opening a browser.

If you want to open a browser, you might be better off looking at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/):

- http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2009/09/selenium-rc-with-python-in-30-seconds.html
- http://jimmyg.org/blog/2009/getting-started-with-selenium-and-python.html
- http://seleniumhq.org/